# Git ignore all files except those of a particular extension, even under subdirectories

Tags: git

How can I ignore all files except those with a particular extension, even consider those located within a subdirectory?

Example: My toy "repository"

```
./foo.xyz  
./tmp/foo.xyz  
./tmp/foo.arg  
./.gitnore
```

I want to keep foo.xyz and tmp/foo.xyz, but not foo.arg

I tried the following:

```
# gitignore file
*                                                                                                           
!*/                                                                                                         
!.gitignore
!*.xyz
```

however foo.arg will not be ignored :(

Any help here on some kind of recursive pattern to go within subdirectories, please?

Comment: Is there a commit in your repo that includes the file `foo.arg`?

Comment: In your pasted text, there are a lot of blanks after the `*` of the second line of `.gitignore` and after the `!*/` of the third line. Are those in the actual file? While trailing spaces are ignored, trailing *tabs* are not, so if there is white-space in there, is it actually all spaces, or are there other forms of white-space?

Comment: What situation has prompted this thought of line for a solution?

Comment: @JSelser No, foo.arg is a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case, make sure your file is called `./.gitignore`, not `./.gitnore` as it is in your question (might be a simple typo).

To make sure files are being ignored, take a file you know is ignored, and type `git check-ignore -v -- afile`: you will see if your .gitignore file is actually in effect or not.

If not, try a:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
git commit -m "apply .gitignore"
```

Comment: `git check-ignore` fixed my problem. I had another rule in the .gitignore file that I did not show in the question, and that rule was actually allowing foo.arg. `git check-ignore` showed me the rule. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

this is a .gitignore file:

```
/Debug/      ignore a folder and all subdirectories.
/Release/
*.sdf        ignore all files in this format. (all in project directory)
sample.txt   ignore a file.
```

I think you added and committed your file to git. and now trying to ignore it.
Not possible. you should delete it from git.